# aadsshlogin extension causes sshd_corrupt

Tags: azure, azure-functions

During adding of AADSSHLogin extension to a VM, following entry is added to /etc/ssh/sshd_config

```
Match User *@*,????????-????-????-????-????????????    # Added by aadsshlogin installer
AuthenticationMethods publickey
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysCommand /usr/sbin/aad_certhandler %u %k
AuthorizedKeysCommandUser root
```

It causes following error in "`sshd -T`" command:

```
$ sudo sshd -T|grep passw
'Match User' in configuration but 'user' not in connection test specification.
```

When above lines are disabled, the command is working without error:

for example:

```
$ sudo sshd -T|grep passw
kerberosorlocalpasswd yes
passwordauthentication no
permitemptypasswords no
```

Is there any workaround that could be done to this change (introduced in sshd_config by Microsoft's AASSSHLogin package) to fix the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> sudo sshd -T|grep passw
> Match User' in configuration but 'user' not in connection test specification.

The above error is marked as bug and can be fixed in the newer versions mentioned in the [GitHub Issues Page](https://github.com/dev-sec/ansible-ssh-hardening/issues/188) but One of the workaround to fix this issue:

- To make it work on all OS's I apparently have to use this:

```
sshd -T -C user=root -C host=localhost -C addr=localhost
```

- Removing the match directive make it work. If I keep the match, adding `-C` is required. According to the man page, `-C` is supposed to be optional and it was indeed the case on older releases.

**References:**

1. [Bug 2858] New: sshd -T requires -C when "Match" is used in sshd_config](http://lists.mindrot.org/pipermail/openssh-bugs/2018-April/019013.html)
2. [Can't get sshd_config Match User to work](https://superuser.com/questions/998206/cant-get-sshd-config-match-user-to-work)
3. [How To Tune your SSH Daemon Configuration on a Linux VPS](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-tune-your-ssh-daemon-configuration-on-a-linux-vps)